# How can I write this format of a dictionary into a csv?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am struggling to write this dictionary in this format to a csv. I am able to populate all of the CSV columns correctly however I am unable to populate the final column with the proper data.

```py
{
    'file.txt': 
        [
            'Bot2',
            {
                '0000022059191883 ': 'NOT_ONLINE',
                '0000008352872313 ': 'true : '
            }
        ]
}
```

I have tried to write to the CSV with using this code, and as mentioned before the last column is incorrect.

```py
for key in info_dict:
    for power_time_stamp in info_dict[key][1]:
        string = key + ',' + 
            info_dict[key][0] + ',' + 
            power_status + ',' + 
            power_time_stamp + ',' + 
            vertical_status + ',' + 
            vertical_time_stamp + '\n'
        f.write(string)
```

I know that I'm missing a loop for `vertical_time_stamp` to be written to the CSV mainly because I'm unsure how to structure the loop correctly.

EDIT:

```
csv_columns = [
    'File_Name',
    'Bot_#',
    'Power Status',
    'Power_Time_Stamp',
    'Vertical_Status',
    'Vertical_Time_Stamp'
]
```

In regards to mapping the columns based off the dictionary print example:

```
Filename : file.txt
Bot # : Bot2
Power Status: NOT_ONLINE
Power Time Stamp : 0000022059191883
Vetical Status : true :
Vertical Time Stamp : 0000008352872313
```

Comment: What kind of output format are you trying to achieve? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: csv_columns = ['File_Name', 'Bot_#', 'Power Status', 'Power_Time_Stamp', 'Vertical_Status', 'Vertical_Time_Stamp']

Comment: what are values?

Comment: In your post, please, comments are difficult to read, easy to miss, and far less permanent.

Comment: Can you give us a map of each column name to the value you expect for it from your example ?

Comment: Why you not use the csv module?

Answer (score 0):

Trying keeping as much of the original code

```
for file_name, record in info_dict.items():
    bot_id = record[0]
    power_time_stamps, vertical_time_stamp = record[1].keys()

    power_status, vertical_status = record[1].values()


    string = file_name + ', '  + ', ' + power_status + ', ' + power_time_stamp + ', ' + vertical_status + ', ' + vertical_time_stamp + '\n'
    f.write(string)
```

For greater readability and performance we can use `join` instead concatenation, also string is not best variable name:

```
   row = ", ".join([file_name, bot_id, power_status, power_time_stampt, vertical status, vertical_time_stamp])
```

Note that only the latest version of python guaranties order of keys in the dictionary, for early versions you would need to check types to distinguish vertical and power data. Also you can use csv module to write to csv files (check another answer).

Comment: Would you suggest writing this in python 3?

Comment: the latest version of it

Comment: Instead of joining and and concatenating strings to generate a CSV record, why don't you simply create a list of the fields and use the standard library [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to write it to the CSV file? You will have a cleaner code by doing that.

Comment: I think that's the right way to go about this, the dictionary has been giving me too . many issues

Comment: @Serge, check my answer. If you amend yours with the `csv` module part, I will delete it and leave just yours since I just picked up from where you left.

Answer (score 0):

I'm picking up from Serge's answer and posting an alternative version using the standard library [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

```py
import csv

info_dict = { 'file.txt': [
    'Bot2', {
    '0000022059191883 ': 'NOT_ONLINE',
    '0000008352872313 ': 'true : '
    }
]}

headers = [
    'File Name',
    'Bot #',
    'Power Status',
    'Power Timestamp',
    'Vertical Status',
    'Vertical Timestamp'
]

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    writer.writerow(headers)

    for fname in info_dict:
        bot_id, rec = info_dict[fname]

        timestamps = rec.keys()

        statuses = rec.values()

        writer.writerow([
            fname,
            bot_id,
            statuses[0],
            timestamps[0],
            statuses[1],
            timestamps[1]
        ])
```

It is not tested though. I'm assuming Serge's code is populating the variables with the right values.

The objective here is to show how to eliminate the string concatenation and how to use the `csv` module.